# Bing Maps V8 -Uncaught ReferenceError: Microsoft is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, bing-maps, bing-api

I am using bing map in my application for searching.
Bing map V8 control.

I have used this CDN

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap&key=api_key' async defer></script>
```

after that when I am trying to use Microsoft.Maps. It is saying:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Microsoft is not defined

new Microsoft.Maps.Color(100,100,0,100);
```

Any one have idea about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `async` while loading Bing API,

```
<script src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap&key=api_key'
          type='text/javascript' ></script>
```

And if you are using jQuery then add [$.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready) to use `maps` like

```
<script>
   $(function(){
       var color = new Microsoft.Maps.Color(100,100,0,100); 
       ....
   });    
</script>
```

Comment: I followed your steps, but I am still getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: Microsoft is not defined`. :/

Comment: Hope you have included jQuery and bing maps api before the $.ready function.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar error while using bing maps js sdk. All you have to do is to add 'windows.' before you write: `Microsoft.Maps.Color(100,100,0,100);`

So now the new code is :

`new window.Microsoft.Maps.Color(100,100,0,100);`